# Does Google Analytics show Bing or Yahoo search keywords under organic when traffic was sent by an affiliate?

Tags: google-analytics, bing, yahoo, affiliate, campaigns

This is a very specific problem and I have two questions to ask regarding it.

Recently, it came to my attention that an outside affiliate was buying PPC search words for a term on Yahoo and Bing. However, when we checked that specific term in our Google Analytics it only shows up as an organic keyword and not as a paid keyword which it is.

To help better understand the whole situation, we do use URL tags with our affiliates but they aren't Google utm tags, they are custom in-house tags.

I have two questions in regards to this:
First, I'm worried if other Bing and Yahoo paid traffic is being counted as organic traffic in GA. Does GA require extra tagging to distinguish non-Google paid and organic search traffic?

Second, to filter these results out from GA would I use a referral filter or a campaign target URL filter? Specifically, I'm trying to filter out just the visits based on the specific tag we have on the ad but I'm not sure which filter I need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics **does** require tagging to distinguish organic and paid traffic.   If traffic does not have *utm* tags, then Google assumes that it is organic.

If you have an affiliate parameter on the URL that is not a *utm* parameter, you can [use JavaScript to inform Google Analytics about the campaign](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference):

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'Affiliates');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Affiliate Bob');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'paid');
ga('set', 'campaignContent', 'Ad by Bob');
```